# const - Shouldn't it not change

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

In running this C++ code, I expected the output to be `Abc`, but, it was `FFF`, why is that? Isn't `name` pointing to a constant `char`?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    const char* name = "Abc";
    name = "FFF";
    std::cout<<name<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I advise you to read this post about [const](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const)

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it's pointing to a `const char` as you say, but it is not a constant pointer.  You are changing what you are pointing to, not the contents of what you are pointing to.  In other words, the memory holding "Abc" still holds the characters "Abc" after you reassign the pointer.

For a constant pointer, you want `const char* const name = "Abc";`.  In this case, it won't compile since you can't change what the pointer points to.

In general, with `const` and pointers in C++, you can read the type name from right-to-left to get a feel for what is going on.  For example, in the `const char* const` case, you can read this as "a constant pointer to a character constant".  A little weird, but it works.

Answer (score 6):

const char* name = "Abc"; -> Non const pointer-> name, but data (Abc) is constant

name = "FFF" -> changing pointer(name) to point to FFF.

```
char *p              = "Hello";          // non-const pointer,
                                         // non-const data
const char *p        = "Hello";          // non-const pointer,
                                         // const data
char * const p       = "Hello";          // const pointer,
                                         // non-const data
const char * const p = "Hello";          // const pointer,
                                         // const data
```

Comment: This is (one reason. The other being the typdef rule) why I prefer to always put the const on the right. It makes this rule easier to parse. `char const * const p`. Read right to left: `p is a "constant *" to "constant char"`

Comment: For some reason, I never had any issues reading `const char*` properly. It always naturally felt that `const` belongs to `char`.

Comment: @Mephane: Sure. But now stick a typedef in there and see what the meaning becomes (if you are not careful it changes (when const is first)) but is consistent when const is placed on the left of the object.

Comment: I know. That's why I don't typedef pointers unless absolutely unavoidable (a situation I have yet to encounter). The problem with typedefs on pointers is that you can only make the pointer value const using the alias created by the typedef, you need a seperate typedef for a pointer-to-const. I prefer just using the C++ keywords instead.

Answer (score 3):

With `const char* name = "Abc";` you are telling compiler you will not change the *contents* of "Abc" using `name`. However, you are free to change the pointer to point to a different memory location. See this [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.5) for details.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known issue with `const` and English speakers.

The syntax allows both:

- `const T`
- `T const`

and both have the same meaning.

However it becomes complicated once you throw a pointer in the mix:

- `const T*` should be read `(const T)*`
- `T const*` should be read `(T const)*`
- `T* const` should be read `(T*) const`

For that reason I am an adept of always using `const` on the immediate right of the object. This is more consistent.

Note that the same issue can be found with `typedef`, let's define `typedef T* pointer`:

- `const pointer` means `T* const`, not `const T*` (as a macro would imply)
- `pointer const` means `T* const`, like the textual replacement

If you take the habit of putting the `const` after the name, and not before like an adjective in English, then you won't fall into those traps.

Comment: Wouldn't `T* const` be read as `T(* const)` as `constant pointer to T`?

Answer (score 2):

in deed the most correct syntax is

```
char const * pName;
```

because `const` keyword apply namely to the part on the left hand side.

if you want a const poitner to a const char you would write it:

```
char const * const pName;
```

and a const pointer to an int;

```
int * const pInt;
```

PS: but I still write the const at the begining of the line whenever I can, an anchored habbit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* name = "Abc";
```

Actually this means, name is a pointer to the const data. Means, **it's the data which is const, not the pointer itself**. So it's perfectly valid if you write:

```
name = "FFF"; //ok : changing the pointer
```

However, the following will not compile:

```
 char * const name = "Abc"; //const pointer to the non-const data!
 name = "FFF"; //error: trying to change the pointer itself!
```

See the compiler error:

> prog.cpp:5: error: assignment of
>   read-only variable ‘name’

See yourself here : http://www.ideone.com/KyNXx

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable as

```
const T* ptr = /*...*/
```

You are declaring a pointer saying that the object being pointed at, not the pointer, must not change.  In other words, it's a "pointer to a T that's const."

If you want to make it impossible to reassign the pointer, you can write

```
T* const ptr = /*...*/
```

This is now an immutable pointer to a T, which can be modified.

You can combine these together like this:

```
const T* const ptr = /*...*/
```

To get an immutable pointer to an immutable T.

As a fun hint, you can usually determine what parts of a pointer/pointed pair can be modified by reading the type right-to-left.  Try that out on the above and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

First, `const` is only checked at compilation time. If it compiles, all operations will be done normally at runtime.

In your example, `const` applies to the content pointed by `name`. So you are allowed to change the pointer, but not the content.

```
strcpy(name, "FFF");
```

would be refused, but not changing the pointer like you did.

Answer (score 0):

The literal strings "Abc" and "FFF" *are* constant, but `name` is a variable  (pointer to constant data).  You have simply changed the variable to point to different constant data.

Moreover while in this case the data was necessarily constant, a pointer to constant data only means that the data cannot be modified by dereferencing that pointer, the data might also be modified directly or through a different pointer. E.g.

```
int i = 0 ;
const int* p = &i ;
i++ ; // valid
(*p)++ // error.
```